# Why does my program print an item more than once in a text file?

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv

I am having some problems fixing something in my code. When I run the program once, the program causes an item to be printed out more than once on one single line in my text file.

[This is what happens when I run my code. The text file is so the user knows what items need to be restocked](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tG4JD.png)

[This is my CSV file which is called 'blank file' and is attached to the variable blank. It is where the new stock levels are written](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XOXTI.png)

[This is my original CSV file which holds all the product information](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gcW6V.png)

This is my code:

```
import csv
data=open('Product information.csv', 'rt')
purchase=csv.reader(data)
blank=open('Blank file.csv', 'wt', newline='')
blank_write=csv.writer(blank)
reorder=open('Reorders.txt', 'wt')

order=input('Please enter the GTIN-8 code of the product you would like to purchase: ')
quantity=int(input('Please enter the amount of this product you want to buy: '))
for row in purchase:
    GTIN=row[0]
    item=row[1]
    price=row[2]
    stock=row[3]
    reorder_level=row[4]
    target_stock=row[5]
    if order==GTIN:
        stock=int(stock)-quantity
    blank_write.writerows([[GTIN,item,price,stock,reorder_level,target_stock]])
data.close()
blank.close()
blank2=open('Blank file.csv', 'rt')
blank_write2=csv.reader(blank2)
choice=input('Please enter yes to check the current stock levels: ')
if choice=='yes':
    for row in blank_write2:
        for field in row:
            GTIN=row[0]
            item=row[1]
            price=row[2]
            stock=int(row[3])
            reorder_level=int(row[4])
            target_stock=int(row[5])
            if stock<=reorder_level:
                amount_to_restock=target_stock-stock
                reorder_file=('{} {} {} {} {} {} {}'.format(row[0]+'   ', row[1]+'   ', '{:10.2f}'.format(float(row[2]))+'   ', str(stock)+'   ', str(reorder_level)+'   ', str(target_stock)+'   ', str(amount_to_restock)))
                reorder.write(reorder_file)
blank2.close()
reorder.close()
```

Everything works fine apart from that problem.

Comment: Please take a look at [Why are fellow users removing thank-you's from my questions?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/328379/why-are-fellow-users-removing-thank-yous-from-my-questions)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realised how to fix it.

I just add to remove the `for field in row:`